# Making a map to replace special characters with ascii characters

Tags: java, dictionary

(Homework Disclaimer)
I'm trying to create a map for some special characters not found in the 128 Ascii.
When the character is found, I need to replace it with a character found in Ascii close to it. The data is coming in from a file that has text like

E.g

```
543|Misèrables, Les (1995)
543|Miserables, Les (1995)
```

The second line is how it should look after I correctly use my map.

Here is my map

```
 Map<Integer, Character> ascMap = new HashMap<>();
 //ascMap.put(246, 'o');
 //ascMap.put(232, 'e');

 ascMap.put('ö' , 'o');
 ascMap.put('è' , 'e');
```

and the rest of my code.

```
String newMovieLine = null;
String store = null;
String empty = null;

int movieCount = 0;
int ascCount = 0;

//System.out.println(ascMap);

    try {
            FileReader readFile = new FileReader(movieFile);

            BufferedReader buffMovie = new BufferedReader(readFile);


            //read while stream is not empty
            while ((empty = buffMovie.readLine()) != null){

                    if(isAscii(empty) == false){

                    store = empty;
                    newMovieLine = empty;

      movieCount++;                        
      System.out.println(store);   //print each line withnon ascii characters

                    System.out.println(" ");

                    }

                    //check the value for ascii
                    for(int j = 0, n = empty.length(); j < n; j++){

                    char asc = empty.charAt(j);

                            if( asc > 127 ){

                            ascCount++;

                            }
                            if( asc == 246 ){

                             asc = ascMap.get(246);
                             newMovieLine = newMovieLine.replace('ö'  , 'o');
                            }

                            else if( asc == 232 ){

                            asc = ascMap.get(232);
                    newMovieLine = newMovieLine.replace('è','e');

 }}}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The current version does not do replace the character. So my question is what am I doing wrong?  I've replace the 232 with the special character in my if statements, no result. I've done countless other things but I just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your Map declaration, you have `Map<Integer,Character>`

Should be `Map<Character,Character>`.

How's 470 treating ya? :p

Comment: Rough. It's been a rough semester. But I actually found out it was easier to replace my input string.  But no it was the actual map declaration.